# how to select particular values defined in one tensor with data in another tensor

Tags: python, variables, tensorflow

I have a tensor variable y ( `tf.shape(y) => [140,8]`) and another variable `x = tf.constant([2,4,5,7],tf.int32)`

I want to select all rows and columns [2,4,5,7] as mentioned in x for data in y.

In Matlab I can simply define `req_data = y[:,x]` gives me the selected columns in x for y data. 
how to do it in tensorflow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do `req_data = y[:,x]`
first use `tf.transpose`, so the shape of tensor will be (8, 140)
then use `tf.gather` to select the data
because `tf.gather` only work on axis=0, so transpose first
then transpose back

```
a = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                 [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]])
a_trans = tf.transpose(a)
b = tf.constant([2,4,5,7])
c = tf.gather(a_trans, b)
c_trans = tf.transpose(c)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.run(c_trans)
    #output [[3  5  6  8]
    #        [13 15 16 18]]
```